# Web API to make phone calls

Tags: api, telephony

is there an API to make phone calls **an have a phone conversation** in the web (maybe flash based?), like skype but without having to install software?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These will allow conversations:

http://www.callfire.com/dialer/cm/info/phone_call_api.html

http://www.callfire.com/dev/index.php/Click_to_call_API

http://public.ifbyphone.com/partners/developers

http://cloudvox.com/

See section Connect Cell Phones and Land Lines:

http://www.twilio.com/how-twilio-works

any US or Canadian phone number and connect the caller to that person.Enter one phone number, or many! If you specify multiple numbers, Twilio will ring them all until somebody answers.

Comment: Let me know if you need more.

Comment: can you have person-to-person conversations through these APIs or is just to broadcast a message or "click 5 to..."

Comment: According to above providers they do provide person to person calls, I changed some of the links to be more specific to what you are looking for.

Comment: I would think this answers your question.

Comment: Do you know of other APIs out there Vecdid? I'd be interested in exploring other options. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

http://api.hoiio.com/voice_call.html

The voice API by [Hoiio](http://developer.hoiio.com) connects 2 phone numbers. Support is international, to over 200 countries.

Answer (score 0):

Victor: Yes, at least with Cloudvox and probably the others.  Can place calls, receive them, connect two parties, connect two parties plus your script, or let people conference (also controlled by your code).

Home page & tour has the basics, and lots of code samples at http://help.cloudvox.com/ -Troy, Cloudvox

Answer (score 0):

I would also hit the latest version of the CallFire API. It is a lot more developer-friendly. You should be able to launch phone calls and send text messages both in bulk or one-offs. https://developers.callfire.com/