# What libraries/APIs allow me access real time audio waveforms of a phone call?

Tags: audio, voip, webrtc, twilio, plivo

I am looking to build an app that needs to process incoming audio on a phone call in real time.
WebRTC allows for this but i think this works only in their browser based P2P audio communications functionality but not for phone calls/ VOIP.

Twilio and Plivo allow you record the audio for batch/later processing.

Is there a library that will give me access to the audio streams in real time? If not, what would I need to build such a service from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, there are APIs, however, how is the phone call going to be pushed through your server when connected? Or is this going to be a cell phone app?

Comment: Nice. So the idea is to have my server initiate a phone call (via some api) with some phone number and then to process the audio coming in from the phone call on the server and based on results of processing take an action/ series of actions on the server. Make sense?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213160/web-api-to-make-phone-calls

Comment: Thanks but these don't allow for real time audio processing.

Comment: Did  you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a media server (so that the call is not longe P2P but it's mediated by the media server using a B2B model), then perhaps the [Kurento Media Server](http://www.kurento.org) may solve your problem. Kurento Media Server makes possible to create processing capabilities which are applyied in real time onto the media streams. There are many examples in the [documentation](http://www.kurento.org/documentation) of computer vision and augmented reality algorithms applied in real time over the video streams. I've never seen an only-audio processing module, but it should be simple to implement just by creating an additional module, which is not too complex if you have some knowledge about C/C++ and media processing concepts.

Disclaimer: I'm part of the Kurento development team.

Comment: does kurento talk to phone networks or its just a streaming server that takes audio from a more specialized library

Comment: Kurento provides different connectors for receiving/sending media including WebRTC and RTP. Hence, it can communicate with a WebRTC capable browser and it can also communicate with a PBX providing RTP support (e.g. Asterisk).